# Simple not selector not working in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a simple example explaining the not selector in CSS. I am expecting every element to have the border red. But none is having. Where is the problem?

```css
[name!='er']{border:2px solid red;}
```

```html
<p name='peter'>This is paragraph 1.</p>

<p name='julie'>This is paragraph 2.</p>

<p name='jennifer'>This is paragraph 3.</p>

<p name='george'>This is paragraph 4.</p>

<p name='gilbert'>This is paragraph 6.</p>

<span name='rosy'>This is span 1.</span>

<span name='robert'>This is span 2.</span>
```

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

This selector exists in jQuery. I hoped same for CSS also. Isn't it?

Comment: Every element? What do you expect your selector to do exactly? There is no such selector (!=) in css

Comment: `name!="er"` is not the `not` selector

Comment: "This selector exists in jQuery. I hoped same for CSS also. Isn't it?" I dunno, what does the link tell you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how your selector should be.

`:not([name='er'])`

You need to know about [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) operator.

```css
*:not([name='er']) {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p name='peter'>This is paragraph 1.</p>

<p name='julie'>This is paragraph 2.</p>

<p name='jennifer'>This is paragraph 3.</p>

<p name='george'>This is paragraph 4.</p>

<p name='gilbert'>This is paragraph 6.</p>

<span name='rosy'>This is span 1.</span>

<span name='robert'>This is span 2.</span>
```

Comment: "You need to know about :not operator." You probably need to brush up too. Those two * shouldn't be there. The whitespace between the first * and :not() is significant. The second * works in certain browsers, sure, but there is no reason whatsoever to have it inside a :not(), and furthermore, compound selectors in :not() doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks. i just updated two things that you said. And also i hope all modern browsers will support `:not` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `:not` selector?

```
:not([name='er']) { 
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```